# Python: Calculate percent return on for forex data in 6 hour intervals

Tags: python, datetime

I have a forex data set which contains the date, time, open, high, low and close over a 1 year period in 1 minute increments.

I'd like to calculate the percent return over a 6-hour interval. My current code:

```
def perc_return(time_interval, data_dict):
    p_returns = []
    for element in data_dict:
        next_element_time = element + timedelta(hours=time_interval)
        print next_element_time
        if next_element_time in data_dict:
            p_return = ((data_dict[next_element_time][1] -
            data_dict[element][0])/data_dict[element][0])*100
            p_returns.append([element, next_element_time, p_return])
        else:
            break
    return p_returns

price_dict = {}
for sample in raw_samples:
    price_dict[sample[0]] = [Decimal(sample[1]), Decimal(sample[4])]

p_returns = perc_return(6, price_dict)
```

This code takes the raw data and converts it into a dictionary with the timestamp as the key and the open and close as the value, then uses that to calculate the 6 hour percent returns. The problem with this, is, bizarrely, adding 6 hours somehow changes the date by several months. Furthermore, this doesn't work if the next date is not in the dataset (for example if the date is a holiday or if the market is closed) so it does not traverse the entire dataset.

Sample output:

```
2007-10-24 03:14:00
2007-03-16 11:19:00
2007-07-25 14:43:00
[[datetime.datetime(2007, 10, 23, 21, 14), datetime.datetime(2007, 10, 24, 3, 14), Decimal('-0.3296857463524130190796857464')], [datetime.datetime(2007, 3, 16, 5, 19), datetime.datetime(2007, 3, 16, 11, 19), Decimal('-0.03752626838787151005703992795')]]
```

My raw dataset:

```
2007.01.01,20:00,1.323700,1.323700,1.323600,1.323700,0
2007.01.01,20:01,1.323600,1.323700,1.323600,1.323600,0
2007.01.01,20:02,1.323700,1.323800,1.323600,1.323600,0
2007.01.01,20:03,1.323700,1.323700,1.323600,1.323600,0
2007.01.01,20:04,1.323500,1.323600,1.323500,1.323500,0
2007.01.01,20:05,1.323600,1.323700,1.323500,1.323700,0
...
```

Are there any other libraries available to python that could do this without these errors?

**EDIT** Some more information that was requested:

Regarding the break and what I want to do if the 6 hour interval does not exist, basically, my originial (naive) thought process was that if this happens, that must mean I've reached the end point of the dataset (hence the break). However, ideally I'd like to retrieve the nearest datapoint to the 6 hour interval as possible.

`element` is simply a `datetime` object containing the timestamp. It looks like this:

```
2007-10-24 03:14:00
```

Finally, regarding the error, if you look at the output, the first three lines describe the `next_element_time`, that is the time after adding 6 hours, notice that they are not in any recognizable order and skip entire months. I now realize this is because the dictionaries in python are unordered when they built/accessed. This issue can probably be fixed using sets or another, ordered, data structure, however I still need help dividing the dataset into 6 hour intervals to take the percent return.

Comment: "The problem with this, is, bizarrely, adding 6 hours somehow changes the date by several months." Could you give an example of where that's happening? I can't spot the issue in your example output.

Comment: For you other question, what do you want to have happen if the "6 hours later" date isn't in the data set? Right now you're `break`ing out of the loop, which doesn't seem to make sense. Maybe you want to skip that interval instead, or maybe use the next available data point, or maybe something else? You haven't said what you want to do, so it's impossible to help you to do it.

Comment: Using other python libaries is not going to fix broken code. Adding 6 hours works fine over here. So what would be an example of the value of `element`, before you add 6 hours to it?

Comment: I've added the requested information

Comment: @Hbhs So now you realize that adding 6 hours is working fine, and you have a plan for what to do when the "6 hours later" time isn't there. Have you tried to actually implement that plan? If so, what trouble have you run into?

Comment: @smarx The trouble is I don't know how to implement that plan. That is, how do I choose the nearest time entry when the 6 hours later entry is not there?